# What is the limit of the following sum

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\Big(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\Big)$$

According to me, the answer is $0$. I'm curious as to what answers might others come up with, as well as the method of reasoning.

Comment: @Victor The limit is strictly positive.

Comment: @lisyarus Obvious though it might be, it's false.  The first term is $\ln 2$, and the limit is $1/2$.

Comment: How is the first term ln2 ? It should be something really close to 1 since 1/n^2->0.

Comment: @Victor The first term of the sequence has $n=1$.

Comment: The first term of the series has k=1 and n->Infinity

Comment: @Victor We are looking at a sequence of series, not just one.  The first series sums to $\ln 2$.

Comment: The majority of responses seem to be saying that the answer is 1/2. As such, can anyone explain what's wrong with the following basic proof for the answer being 0? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(1+\frac{k}{n^2}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2}) + \ln(1+\frac{2}{n^2}) + \cdots + \ln(1+\frac{n}{n^2})\Big)$$ $$ = \lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2}) + \ln(1+\frac{2}{n^2}) + \cdots + \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})\Big) $$ $$ = \ln(1+0) + \ln(1+0) + \cdots + \ln(1+0) = 0$$ Is there an error in the above logic? Qualitatively speaking, is the issue that I'm ignoring the infinite number of

Comment: @ssmolen At the end, you have an infinite number of terms. In other words, you have something of the form $\infty \cdot 0$, which is indeterminate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any $n$ this is a Riemann sum of the integral $$ \int_0^1\log\left((1+\frac{x}{n})^n\right)dx$$ and its error is less than $1/n$.  Now the integrand converges to $x$ for $n\to\infty$ so these sums converge to $\tfrac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 10):

Rather boring answer:

We have $x-{x^2 \over 2} \le \log(1+x) \le x$ for all $x >0$.

We have
$\sum_{k=1}^n  \log(1+ { k \over n^2}) \le \sum_{k=1}^n { k \over n^2} = {1 \over n^2} (1+2 + \cdots + n) = {1 \over n^2} {1 \over 2} n (n+1)$.

We also have $\sum_{k=1}^n \log(1+ { k \over n^2}) \ge  \sum_{k=1}^n ( { k \over n^2} -{ 1\over 2} ({ k \over n^2})^2 ) = {1 \over n^2} {1 \over 2} n (n+1) - { 1\over 2} {1 \over n^4} (1^2+2^2+\cdots + n^2)$.

Since $1^2+2^2+\cdots + n^2 = {1 \over 3} n^3 + {1 \over 2} n^2 +{1 \over 6} n$, we 
 see that the limit of the sum is ${ 1\over 2}$.

Comment: Boring, maybe. But it is simple, and easily gives error bounds.

Comment: I don't see how it is boring. A simpler proof is far better because it appeals to a larger audience (including me) with limited knowledge. I prefer not to use cannons to kills insects. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Your answer can't be right**

We have, if $x_k>0$, that $$\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+x_k\right) \geq 1+x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$$

So $$\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right) \geq 1+\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}$$

So , as $n\to\infty$, this is at least $\frac{3}{2}$, so your limit, if it exists, must be greater than $\log\left(\frac32\right)>0$.

**Correct Answer**

Using that, for $0<x<1$, $\log(1+x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^{i-1}\frac{x^i}{i}$, we can see that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{in^{2i}}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^i$$

But $\sum_{k=1}^n k^i \leq n^{i+1}$, so $$\frac{1}{n^{2i}}\sum_1^n k^i < \frac{1}{n^{i-1}}$$ and therefore,  $$\left|\sum_{i=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{in^{2i}}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^i\right|<\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac {1}{n^{i-1}} = \frac{1}{n-1}\to 0$$

So the only term that matters is $i=1$ as $n\to\infty$.

The first term is $\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n^2+n}{2n^2} \to \frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of writing your sum is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)=\log\left(\frac{(n^2+n)!}{n^2!}\right)-2n\log(n)
$$
We can use [Stirling's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to get
$$
\log((n^2+n)!)=(n^2+n)\log(n^2+n)-(n^2+n)+\frac12\log(2\pi(n^2+n))+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\log(n^2!)
&=n^2\log(n^2)-n^2+\frac12\log(2\pi n^2)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\\
&=(n^2+n)\log(n^2)-n\log(n^2)-n^2+\frac12\log(2\pi n^2)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting yields
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{(n^2+n)!}{n^2!}\right)
&=\left(n^2+n+\frac12\right)\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)+2n\log(n)-n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\\
&=\left(n^2+n+\frac12\right)\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)\\
&+2n\log(n)-n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\\
&=2n\log(n)+\frac12+\frac1{3n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)=\frac12+\frac1{3n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
$$
and the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)=\frac12
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(1+k/n^2)$$
$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^n(1+k/n^2)\right)=^*\ln(\sqrt e)=\frac12\ne0$$
__

**[$^*\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} (1/n^2)^n (1+n^2)_n = \sqrt e$ from here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cprod_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%281%2Bk%2Fn%5E2%29)**

Comment: where does the \sqrt e come from ?

Comment: Certainly, not equal...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can you elaborate as to which two quantities are not equal, sorry to poke

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I think it is equal...

Comment: The $S$ only coverges in the limit, not actually equaly to $S_n$ for any $n$. @copper.hat

Comment: @Aditya $\prod_{k=1}^n (1+k/n^2)$ is a rational number. $\sqrt{e}$ in not a rational number. So they cannot be equal.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: You are correct, of course. I was thinking of the limit...

Comment: You've still pretty much skipped the only part of the problem that is hard, @Aditya.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just wanted to show $0$ is not an answer, I did'nt compute the $\sqrt e$.I used help.

Comment: But you haven't shown that zero is not the answer, you've merely asserted it.

Answer (score 1):

$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{m}{n} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n \ln (1+\frac{k}{mn}) = m \cdot\int_0^1 \ln(1+\frac{x}{m}) = m(m+1)\ln(1+\frac{1}{m})-m$.

This last expression approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ as $m\to \infty$.

This is not quite a proof, but we can make it into one by carefully bounding the difference between the sum and the integral.