# how to factor this series?

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

I have thought for hours but got no clue how to get this infinite product

> Once these expressions are substituted into $(2.5)$, all the real terms in the brackets (the terms in even powers of $x$) cancel out. As soon as the common factor of $2ix$ is factored out in the remaining odd-power terms of $x$, the right-hand side of $(2.5)$ reduces to a compact form, and we have
>   $$\sin{x}=x\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2} (-1)^k \binom{2k+1}{n} \frac{x^{2k}}{n^{2k+1}} \tag{2.8}$$
>   Of all the stages in Euler's procedure, which, as a whole, represents a real work of art, the next stage is perhaps the most critical and decisive. Factoring the polynomial in $(2.8)$ into the trigonometric form
>   $$\sin{x}=x\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}\left[1-\frac{(1+\cos 2k\pi/n)x^2}{(1-\cos 2k\pi/n)n^2}\right]$$

An excerpt from the book *'Greens functions and infinite Products'* written by Melnikov Yu.

Comment: this is a step in the proof of the infinite product of Sin(x)

Comment: An excerpt from the book 'Greens functions and infinite Products' written by Melnikov Yu

Comment: Please refrain as much as possible from using images for text. It makes questions more difficult to search. Is my edit correct?

Comment: Sorry, I'm fresh here, and I don't know how to input the formula...

Comment: No problem, there is a [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks a lot ...

Comment: [Related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377369/infinite-product-representation-of-sin-x)

Comment: @KeithMcClary it is on a book , and maybe its a conclusion.